# Apk open in extract form

Tags: android, apk

I have made an application and build a signed apk and upload the apk to the website but when downloading it from google chrome it opens in this format however if I download it from UC browser or from file manager it works fine

IMAGE

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's your question? What do you want to be able to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: All the files in my application extract when click on open once apk downloading finished

Comment: Please edit your question to include the above and clarify whether the above is what *happens*, or is what you *want* to happen.

Comment: Above is happened I want to simply install the apk once the download is finished but unfortunately apk is open like above

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to use it on other device, it may work.
It can be your devices' default action on particular file type extension. 
In this case the `.APK` extension.
You can clear you preference of default action in application settings.